# Scrape external webpage for first image and add it to new post

Tags: php, functions, images, urls

I'm looking for a way to scrape an external page for its first/best/largest image and insert a copy of that image as the featured image of a new post on my Wordpress site.

The way that I was hoping this would work would be that a user of my site would enter the URL of an external webpage into a form, and it would scrape that page for its first/best/largest image and set it as the featured image of a new post, which would then be published upon submission of the form. I have the front-end post submission set up with [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) which allows users of my site to create new posts, but I am confused with the backend web scraping part of it.

Is it possible to achieve this in Wordpress? Maybe using the [HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API)? I'm not a programmer so the HTTP API is a little intimidating to me. I'm hoping someone here with more programming knowledge than me that is familiar with Wordpress can help.

Comment: scrape URL for its first image? Do you mean wp post's first image? There are several answers to that on stackexchange.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my question to be clearer on what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as referenced [here](http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-featured-image-url/)

but you are talking about a great deal of customization in the Gravity forms plugin and like you said you are not a programmer yourself, so you better open a support ticket in their forums and they might be able to help.

Also look at this code that can help you if you decide to do it yourself

```
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
$filename = basename($image_url);
if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
else
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

$image_url is what you will get from user input / upload.

Comment: Is there a way to scrape an image from a page where the URL isn't of the image? Like a blog post with an image for example? I will follow your advice and open a support ticket at the Gravity Forms website.